# Read columns in php with mysqli_query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to read from an SQL file where I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tariff` (
    `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `price_single` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `price_double` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `totalroom` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    primary key(`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and I inserted:

```
INSERT INTO `tariff` (`type`, `price_single`, `price_double`, `totalroom`) VALUES
('Standard', '2600', '3100', 100),
('Deluxe', '3100', '4200', 50),
('Super Deluxe', '3800', '4600', 15);
```

next I have :

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$unm = "root";
$pwd = "root";
$db = "hotel";
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $unm, $pwd, $db);
$qrysel = "select * from tariff";
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $qrysel);

if (!$rs) {
    echo "here it stops";
    die($qrysel);
}

while ($v = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$v['type']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$v[1]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$v[2]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$v[3]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

I don't know where is the problem. I'm trying to output what I have done in the insert in the SQL file but it goes into the if-statement and there it stops.

Comment: So tell us: what do you see in your http servers error log file?

Comment: your query failed then and you need to find out why.

Comment: I bet the connection to the database server did _not_ work and you have `FALSE` inside `$con` which you never realize since you blindly trust that the connection works instead of checking it.

Answer (score 2):

Your Query looks just fine what i assume is there is an error while connecting to database you should first do some error handling to see whether it is connecting to the database or not here's a solution for error handling in db connectivity

```
$server="localhost";
        $unm="root";
        $pwd="root";
        $db="hotel";
        $con=mysqli_connect($server,$unm,$pwd,$db);

if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error($con));
}
```

if there is a database error i recommend using the following credentials

```
$server="localhost";
        $unm="root";
        $pwd="";
        $db="hotel";
        $con=mysqli_connect($server,$unm,$pwd,$db);
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error($con));
}
```

Comment: I tried this method and the error is : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: one more thing kindly make sure whatever server you are using both Apache and Mysql are running

Comment: I have the same error even if I try this , and I am using only Apache. :(

Comment: that is the problem you need to start Mysql as well,which server are you using? xampp? wamp?

Comment: kindly ensure MySql is running on your localhost. Go to Xampp [or other localhost] control panel and click start/run under Mysql ].

Comment: I wasn't using xampp or wamp .But I have the Mysql installed and when I try to start it is says it cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

First try to check the connection:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
```